# Cocos2d-iphone animating transition from one frame to another

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to make animation for one sprite, that one frame fades out so another one is visible? It's like creating two sprites on the same position and the one that is on top looses its opacity. I would like rather to operate on one sprite with two frames than with two sprites.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

A sprite can only display one "frame". For your requirements you **have** to use two sprites, there's no way around that. After all you're displaying two images at the same time, one fading out, the other fading in.